# Avoid -dbg_version packages on apt-cacher-ng server

Tags: apt-cacher

**Intro:** We have created a `apt-cacher-ng` server to provide cached packages to our users that have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. Combined with the cached packages, we are doing a weekly "mirror" of some Ubuntu update uris using the `PrecacheFor` parameter. The following regex will create mirror of all update repos:

```
PrecacheFor: uburep/dists/trusty-updates/*/binary-amd64/Packages*
```

However, it will make cache of debug packages, that are pretty bloated and it will not be useful. **Sample html log output:**

```
Downloading uburep/pool/main/c/ceph/librbd1-dbg_0.80.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb...
<i>(6234KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-base_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
<i>(1380KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-base-core_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
<i>(715KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-base-drivers_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
<i>(515KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-calc_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
<i>(5779KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-common_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb...
<i>(19345KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-core_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
<i>(27243KiB)</i>

Downloading uburep/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-dbg_4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
```

**Question:** Is there a way exclude `-dbg_` substring packages from being downloades using any option of `apt-cacher-ng` or using a uri regex ?

Comment: Sound like it's policy of ubuntu and apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the `DontCache`, `DontCacheRequested`, and `DontCacheResolved` directives. For example, something like:

```
DontCache (^|.*?/).+?-dbg_[0-9]
```

The documentation says that this prevents files from being downloaded and cached, but it doesn't clarify the interactions between `DontCache` and `PreCacheFor`.

Comment: I´ll give it a try during my workhours. Thanks